# How do you reverse the animation of a dropdown menu when you mouse off of it?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a dropdown menu that flies on screen when the menu tab is moused over, but can't seem to get it to reverse the animation and go back offscreen when I mouse off of the tab or dropdown menu.

I've already tried the animation properties like `animation-direction` and `animation-iteration-count`, but none seem to work.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<div id="menu"> <!--The menu bar-->
    <ul class="menulist"> <!--The list in the menu which has the tabs-->
        <li id="menutab"> <!--One of the tabs-->
            <a class="menulinks">tab 1</a> <!--The tab text-->
            <div class="dropdown-content"> <!--The dropdown menu with all the links-->
                <a>link 1</a>
                <a>link 2</a>
                <a>link 3</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the shortened css that has the problems. The full code is here: https://codepen.io/PercyCho/pen/PMqgEg

```css
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: blue;
    min-width: 260px;
    margin-top: 19px;
    z-index: 1;
  /*is there a property or animation that I can put here to reverse the animation once I mouse off of it?*/
    animation-name: dropdown-slide;
    animation-duration: 0.35s;
}

@keyframes dropdown-slide{
    from{transform: translate(-1500px, 0px);} /*-1500px just means off the screen*/
    to{transform: translate(0px, 0px);}/*which then makes it come onscreen */
}

li#menutab:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an animation to get the desired results ...just use the `transform` property with a duration on the `transition` :

```
.dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-1500px, 0px);
    transition : .35s all;
    background-color: blue;
}

li#menutab:hover .dropdown-content {
transform: translate(0px, 0px)
}
```

check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/eqNaBV)

Comment: Thank you so much! I would have never figured that out.